# How to reverse axis in R avoiding unary operator error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset, which resembles data from googleAnalytics:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(dayOfWeek = rep(c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6"), each = 24), 
                      hour = rep(c("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11",
                                   "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"),7),
                      sessions = (ceiling(runif(168,5,80))), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to plot the session hours but with "00" on top and "23" on bottom. That means reversing the axis. I have tried the following code:

```
dataset %>% ggplot(aes(x = dayOfWeek, y = hour, fill = sessions)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'white', high = 'red') + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

It says that is invalid to a unary operator.

Please, could you provide some advice to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Your dayOfWeek and hour columns are characters rather than numbers. Is that what you intended? ggplot is getting confused because you used `scale_y_continuous` but your data is not continuous, it's coded as discrete characters so it doesn't know how to reverse it.

Comment: Hello @MrFlick, as I commented the dataset resembles what googleAnalytics returns. Metrics as sessions come as numeric, but Dimensions as dayOfWeek and Hour come as character.

Comment: Well, i'm not sure why it would do that. That doesn't seem helpful. If it's a character, during your data import/cleaning why not convert to numeric with `as.numeric()` or if it's already become a factor then `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]` or `as.numeric(as.character(x))`. Then point being you shouldn't use a continuous scale on values that aren't continous.

Comment: If I omit the last line then the plot goes well, except that "23" is on top and "00" is at bottom. I tried `scale_y_reverse()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to reorder your character column "hour" before plotting with `ggplot`.

Here, I create a new column which is the numerical conversion of your column "hour", then I sorted the dataframe based on the value of this numerical column and I set the original "hour" column as factor with levels in the right order.

Then, you can plot it and get the desired orientation of your `y` labeling:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% mutate(Hour = as.numeric(hour)) %>% arrange(-Hour) %>%
  mutate(hour = factor(hour, unique(hour))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dayOfWeek, y = hour, fill = sessions)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'white', high = 'red') + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Sunday','Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'))
```

[image]

Does it answer you question ?

Comment: I did answer my question and I thank you (better late than never). Have a great weekend.!